# android - How to change Transparent toolbar's color and size

Tags: java, android, xml, toolbar

My toolbar is Transparent like this ; [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PnKqY.png)

and codes here , textApperarance not working ,I tried other things too like "android:textColorPrimary"

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>

</style>


<style name="AppTheme.ActionBar.Transparent" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/gray</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/TitleTextColor</item>

</style>
<style name="TitleTextColor">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/red</item>
</style>
```

and there is androidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.ActionBar.Transparent">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
       >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".AddNote"></activity>
</application>
```

Answer (score 0):

just replace this one -

```
<style name="AppTheme.ActionBar.Transparent" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/gray</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/TitleTextColor</item>

</style>
```

with this one

```
<style name="AppTheme.ActionBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
   <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
        <item name="windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
 <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/TitleTextColor</item>


</style>
```

Comment: Where do you change the size?